# Is it possible to test Polymer Components outside of a browser?

Tags: polymer-1.0

WCT is great for testing your custom web components, but it requires spinning up a browser to execute the tests.

I am looking for a way to test my components outside of a browser. I looked into jsdom, but it does not currently support Polymer. Any other suggestions?

In case anyone else is following this question, I have made some progress with jsdom. 
The trick thus far has been in the created() method:

```
created: function (error, window) {
    window.document.createRange = function () { }
    window.getSelection = function () { }
    window.Range = function () { }
    window.Selection = function () { }
    window.CanvasRenderingContext2D = function () { } // Object.getPrototypeOf(require("canvas")(0,0).getContext("2d")) might be better
    window.SVGUseElement = window.HTMLUnknownElement
},
```

Comment: why would you try to create polymer elements outside the browser?

Comment: You can spin up a desktop app that uses web elements with something like Electron with Node.js or many equivalents, but I am not sure if that is what you mean. Could you clarify why you want to do this outside a browser, and what you want that to look like?

Comment: I want to be able to run unit tests, and I want them to run fast. I don't want to spin up a browser, or reach out to a selenium server, as that slows things down.

Comment: as for what it would look like... Ideally, I would run a gulp task, and it would finish with a success or failure, perhaps with an output file that my CI server could parse.

Comment: Any progress with this? The comment by solkimicreb on this [jsdom issue](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/1030) seems to indicate that he was able to get polymer (and by extension custom elements) running on a version of jsdom and using a polyfill. Do you have a better solution?